# Natural sorting currencies for datatables

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I found a natural sorting function online that seems to have done the trick for many people. I implemented this natural sorting function into my datatable and it somewhat improved the results I was getting.

The reason I need natural sorting is because I have currency values that are being represented as string.

For example, if I have these values:

```
{"550", "750", "1,250", "850", "2,300", "400"}
```

A natural sorted array should return in this order:

- 400
- 550
- 750
- 850
- 1,250
- 2,300

However, the natural ordering is getting confused with the commas and returns like this instead:

- 1,250
- 2,300
- 400
- 550
- 750
- 850

Is there any way to manipulate the existing function to take into account these commas?

Here is a link to the sorting algorithm that I've been using:
http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural

**EDIT**

Also should've noted that I am using an entity framework where the Balance field in the object is a string but in the database is a decimal. It is essential for the Balance value to be in a string format before it gets added to the object.

Therefore parse methods won't work in this situation, i need to be able to change a part of the actual function that'll allow me to split the comma and read the full number value of the balance.

Answer (score 0):

Your number are interpreted as strings. Try to convert them first: use `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` for currency.

Note there is a sort-function in JS already.

Sources:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: Should've noted that it is impossible to use a parse as the balance database value is being assigned to an object where it automatically gets converted to a string. 

dto.Balance = String.Format("{0:C}", entity.Account.Balance);

That line there assigns it as a currency value. I have to use a natural sort for it to sort properly. I just wish people would answer my question rather than giving me solutions that do not help me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

So i have figured out a solution that works for me. 
In the existing natural sort function, there are two regex variables called `re` and `sre`.

Inside the `re` variable, where `[0-9]` is defined, i changed to `[0-9.-]` to allow negative values. Furthermore, in the `sre` variable, i added an extra `|[ ]*,` which allowed the string replace format to replace all comma values as `""` which ultimately allowed my string to be ordered properly.

Hope this solution helps. The link to the function code is above in the original question.